# Difference within the same column

Tags: difference

So I know this probably looks a little ridiculous, but I am pretty much making a query that makes a query. The issue is I need the part that says

`((transactions.amt_paid WHERE item_no = @item_no - SUM(transactions.amt_paid WHERE item_no IN (SELECT item_no = @items))`

to show me the total, but how do I do a Sum here? Hope that makes sense.

```
DECLARE @aracct VARCHAR(12)
    SET @aracct = '49947368'
DECLARE @item_no VARCHAR(12)
    SET @item_no = '2081'
SELECT tran_id, * 
FROM transactions 
WHERE account = @aracct AND item_no = @item_no

DECLARE @itemtable TABLE (items VARCHAR(6))
INSERT INTO @itemtable VALUES ('2735')
INSERT INTO @itemtable VALUES ('2737')

SELECT 'UPDATE transactions' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'SET amt_paid = ' + '''' + (transactions.amt_paid WHERE item_no = @item_no - SUM(transactions.amt_paid WHERE item_no IN (SELECT item_no = @items)) +
'''' + ' WHERE aracct = ' + '''' + (SELECT @aracct) + '''' + ' AND item_no = ' + '''' + (SELECT @item_no) + ''''
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you need to do?  This helps identify where to go with your question.  Thanks.

Comment: I am wanting to sum the total for values 2735 and 2737 (which if it helps = -231.83) and then I need to subtract that from the  total of line 2081 (which is -12361.34)...so -12361.34 - (-231.83) = -12129.51

Comment: So essentially the end result would be:UPDATE transactions SET amt_paid = '-12129.51' WHERE aracct = @aracct  AND item_no = '2081'

Answer (score 0):

(in the following, looking at your syntax, I'm assuming you're on Sql Server)

What you are asking is called dynamic sql, and you can definitely do it.
"Making a query that makes a query" is quite common in advanced use cases.

Your requirement, however, is *not* an advanced use case.

I am assuming you want to SUM the rows where item_no is equal to @item_no and you want to subtract where item_no is IN @items.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

So, let's tackle this first task, before.

```
Select SUM(CASE
  When (item_no = @item_no) THEN amt_paid
  When (item_no IN (SELECT items FROM @itemtable)) THEN -amt_paid END) TheAmount
FROM transactions
WHERE (item_no = @item_no) OR (item_no IN (SELECT items FROM @itemtable))
```

YAY! Now, if this works as expected, we have a query that returns our value.
And we can do:

```
UPDATE transactions
SET amt_paid = (... the previous query ...)
WHERE aracct = @aracct AND item_no = @item_no
```

Done, without dynamic query.
If you need to print the query, the previous SELECT can be used to give a value to another variable and then generate the query.
I can elaborate further, if you really need the query.

*Edit*: well, it's not easy to help without some extra information, but probably Sql is complaining about the Select inside the max(...)

Try to rewrite the Select in this way:

```
Select SUM(CASE
  When (T.item_no = @item_no) THEN T.amt_paid
  When (IT.items IS NOT NULL) THEN -amt_paid END) TheAmount
FROM transactions T
    LEFT JOIN @itemtable IT ON IT.items = T.item_no
WHERE (item_no = @item_no) OR (item_no IN (SELECT items FROM @itemtable))
```

If you still have problems, please detail your error.

Comment: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.